# Query in access not returning correct result due to join?

Tags: ms-access, join

I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around some queries that I need joined correctly to each other, in order to get the correct result.

Basically I got a database with a sewage network in it, the network has manholes with IDs and pipes with IDs, all pipes are defined with one UpstreamManholeID (OpstroemKnudeID) and a DownstreamManholeID (NedstroemKnudeID) (Knude table = manhole).

When I try to make a query based on observations in the pipe, I keep getting the same PipeID listed for pipes with different Upstream and downstream ID. As shown in the picture below, probably because it only checks for the upstream manhole id before choosing a pipe id.

[image: Query result]

I tried changing the query, but that returns blanks in the PipeID instead.

[image: Second attempt]

To sum up, I need to list the PipeID based on both upstream and downstream node, as it is, I can only get it to check for either upstream or downstream. 
I'm having a hard time explaining, so feel free to ask any clarifying questions you need.

At the moment I'm running two queries, one calling the other, in order to get the almost correct result.

```
SELECT TVInspektion.Startpunktnr AS OpstrømsKnudenavn, TVInspektion.Slutpunktnr AS NedstrømsKnudenavn, Knude.ID AS OP, Knude_1.ID AS Ned
FROM (TVInspektion LEFT JOIN Knude ON TVInspektion.Startpunktnr = Knude.Knudenavn) LEFT JOIN Knude AS Knude_1 ON TVInspektion.Slutpunktnr = Knude_1.Knudenavn;

SELECT [Copy Of Vurderes].OP, [Copy Of Vurderes].OpstrømsKnudenavn, [Copy Of Vurderes].Ned, [Copy Of Vurderes].NedstrømsKnudenavn, Ledning.ID
FROM [Copy Of Vurderes] LEFT JOIN Ledning ON ([Copy Of Vurderes].Ned = Ledning.NedstroemKnudeID) AND ([Copy Of Vurderes].OP = Ledning.OpstroemKnudeID);
```

That returns the following result:

[image: Result from the two queries]

Comment: Please show the generated sql code too

Comment: You need to research `Group By` see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177905(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Add results of your query and then show example of what you'd like it to look like

Comment: Added code and result. 
Problem occurs when going from TVInspektion which uses Manholenames for upstream/downstream, through Knude (which is the manhole table with ID and name) and over too Ledning which uses ManholeIDs for upstream/downstream.